# a question about formal definition of limit

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, intuition

i tried to understand the formal definition of limts, which is

> the function $f$ approaches the limit $l$ near $a$ means; for every $\epsilon >0 $ there is some $\theta$ such that ,for all $x$,if $0<|x-a|<\theta$, then $|f(x)-l|<\epsilon$

my problem is that i cannot understand why $f(x)>l-\epsilon$ for all $\epsilon$.intuitively if we take any fixed $x$ such that  $0<|x-a|<\theta$ we will get $f(x)>l-\epsilon$ just for some $\epsilon$,because we can choose $\epsilon$ very close to $l$ in which $f(x)<l-\epsilon$ .
I really tried to convince myself of this definition, but I could not, because when I look at the curve, I find that it is not true for all $\epsilon$.

Can someone explain more?

Comment: There are various related questions for you to peruse: for instance [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/866107/question-about-epsilon-delta-definition-of-limit?rq=1).

Comment: Is there a specific function $f$ you are looking at? 
Assuming $\lim_{x \to a} f(x)=l$: Given $\epsilon>0$, it is up to the writer (not $\epsilon$ as it is just a positive number with no thoughts) to find $\theta>0$ such that the implication in the formal definition holds true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You start by picking a fixed, but arbitrary $\varepsilon>0$ and then you find $\theta>0$ such that $0<|x-a|<\theta$ implies $|f(x)-l|<\varepsilon$. The order of the quantifiers in the definition implies that $\theta$ depends on $\varepsilon$, so if $\varepsilon$ changes, $\theta$ may also change. This means that you're picking a $\theta$ for each $\varepsilon$ instead of starting by picking a $\theta$ that works for all $\varepsilon$.

Comment: thank you .......

Comment: @unknown I'm glad my answer was helpful. I corrected my answer. The original version had $|f(x)-f(a)|<\varepsilon$ instead of $|f(x)-l|<\varepsilon$.

Comment: yeah, already  i understand what did you mean